# Pass string to server side with Jquery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

i want to send the variable data to server side 
how can i do this?

```
    $("form").submit(function () {
        GetSelectedValues();
    });
    function GetSelectedValues() {
        var data = $("#DDL_WorkCategory").val();

    }
```

this is my code in html

```
      <select id="DDL_WorkCategory" class="form-control select2" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Select a Category" style="width: 100%;" onchange="myfunction();">
                                <option>نحت</option>
                                <option>خزف</option>
                                <option>تصميم</option>
                                <option>تصوير</option>
                                <option>تشكيل</option>
                                <option>ترمييم</option>
                            </select>
```

edited
i do this using hidden field

Comment: can you post your html please??

Comment: If i am not wrong this $("#DDL_WorkCategory") is in form or not

Comment: "#DDL_WorkCategory" no it is in form

Comment: What is the point of posting the form via AJAX in your case ? And what should the user expect when the data nas been posted ? For example the stackoverflow comment are posted via AJAX and display the comment after the data has been posted.  Adding what is the desired interaction could help provide a more complete answer.

Comment: i want to tke the value from DDL_WorkCategory to save it in the sql server

Comment: I recommend to start reading the nice jQuery API documentation and with that knowledge try to find the solution on your own. Start here: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is in form then there is no need to call a separate function to fetch the data of element. You just have to give a name to that element.

```
<select id="DDL_WorkCategory" name"WorkCategory">
    <option>type1</option>
    <option>type1</option>
</select>
```

value of name attribute become key, which you can receive at server end. In above code WorkCategory will be the key to fetch the data at server end.

Comment: this is the answer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32288851/pass-variable-from-java-script-to-aspx-form)

Answer (score 0):

Try `$.post()`:

```
$.post('/target-url', { data: $("#DDL_WorkCategory").val() });
```

Comment: Almost correct but as the tag mention there is probably no PHP involved, and probably more ASPX on the server side

Comment: yes it's aspx not php